# Having an Npx issue while executing npx firestore-algolia-search

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I want to sync my old firestore data of a collection to algolia. I have followed the documentation provided and face issues with npx. If anyone could help me would mean a lot.
Here's the output I get if I use a PowerShell terminal

[image]

/bin/bash: C:/Program Files/nodejs/npx: No such file or directory

I receive this error when using bash in wsl even when providing the full path to npx and the script file.

Any help would mean a lot

I have tried and tested all the solutions I could find on the internet from using git bash to execute the script to using wsl to execute the bash script without any luck

Comment: again tried with bash in ubuntu wsl and going into the directory where script file is and running bash file and is still giving

npm ERR! could not find executabe to run

Comment: You should use npm i firestore-algolia-search according to docs to install

Comment: and yes i have npm and npx installed both on 8.19.2 versions when using npm -v and npx -v respectively

Comment: i have tried that as well and then use npx to execute it. but still doesnt work for some reason

Comment: Your trying to install firestore algolia search package so u should use npm install then the package name

Comment: i have used npm install to install firestore-algolia-search by using the command npm install firestore-algolia-search which does execute.. then later when i use npx firestore-algolia-search to execute it still it gives the same error and i have tried to install it with --global property too. yet still the problem persists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `npx firestore-algolia-search@0.5.14`. Something is broken in 0.5.15.

EDIT: I created a [github ticket](https://github.com/algolia/firestore-algolia-search/issues/138) for this issue.

Comment: thanks! ill use that next time. I have used a custom java script script for now

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't figure out the error I was getting but using version 0.5.14 worked.